# Can we add users to Azure AD Domain Services domain

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We've setup an Azure AD Domain Services, tied to an Azure AD tenant. Is there any way to add users to the managed domain only (to run services) or do they have to exist in the parent Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can add a Custom OU to the managed domain (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/create-ou) and then you can create a user in that to run SQL Server as.
In theory you could setup a group managed service account (gMSA) but I couldn't get that to work (some permissions issue in using the gMSA created).

Answer (score 1):

AAD DS is a layer over AAD like B2C that offers more security functionality.
Users are stored in your AAD tenant.
To run and secure your services/resources you should use Managed identities and Enterprise applications.

Azure SQL Server Managed Identity

Assign an AAD user admin to your server:
[image]

Create a Contained user in your SQL Server:

```
create user [my-app-service] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [my-app-service];
alter role db_datawriter add member [my-app-service];

create user [my-app-service/slots/staging] from external provider;
alter role db_datareader add member [my-app-service/slots/staging];
alter role db_datawriter add member [my-app-service/slots/staging];
```

my-app-service is a placeholder. You will need to replace it with the name of your own app service. Further, for system-assigned identities, different deployment slots have their own individual identities.

Update Your SQL Connection to Use Managed Identities.

Managed Instance is created in the App Service you want to communicate with the SQL Server.
Take this post as reference:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-managed-identity-with-azure-sql-database

Any resource that can connect with your AAD can use Managed Identities.
Managed Identities:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

Hope it shed some light.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to make a managed service account but could not get it going. This is to run SQL Server as.

Comment: Thank you very much - but I mean the user that actually runs SQL Server service. We're setting up an Always-On-AG and having the same user for the service on both machines makes thing easier.